# Workaround for repmgr of PostgreSQL in Windows Server OS 2019

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I have been provided a VM on Windows Server OS 2019 for installing my web-app which uses PostgreSQL 9.6.6 as DBMS. As per the documentation at  [this link](https://repmgr.org/docs/current/install-requirements.html#INSTALL-COMPATIBILITY-MATRIX), there is **There is no support for Microsoft Windows**.

Is there a workaround for configuring a "PostgreSQL Witness Server" with or without using `repmgr`?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but: you shouldn't go into production with 9.6.6 - better use the latest minor version which is 9.6.26 and [fixes 521 bugs](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.6.6&to=9.6.21). Note that 9.6 will be end-of-live in about 7 months, so you need to plan an upgrade to a more recent version (e.g. 13) as well.

Comment: By choosing Windows as your server operating system you excluded yourself from nearly all interesting extensions and tools for high availability and proper backups. If you want a standby server, you will have to use the built-in tools (e.g. `pg_basebackup` to bootstrap the standby) and your own tools to do the failover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ain't sure But I think the solution to problem comes with PostgreSQL 9.6 installer. At the end of Installation, there is StackBuilder Option to Download additional packages. One of the package is for Downloading Slony.

The documentation on Slony is available at [this Link](https://www.slony.info/documentation/1.2/firstdb.html)

Comment: It seems that this option is for replication configuration not for automatic failover.